# White Screen during loading the ViewBasedApplication in iphone

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, iphone

I am new to iPhone. I have Develop one aplication that is of ViewBased Application.
Everything is right but while i run the application, instead of showing list of content it shows the white screen. After doing studies  come to know that it may be for the XIB file references. As my code is right at all. So will u tell me while it appear like it ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which controls are you using in your .xib files?? Are you properly connecting the controls with its hierarchy in File's Owner?????  I want to say that if you are using table view inside the uiview then you must have to set your delegates and datasource with uiview and the uiview must be assciated with the appdelegate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your .xib file and see whether you have link it to datasource and delegate or not.

Answer (score 3):

Check your xib and properly check inteface builder that a datasource and delegate is set or not. for showing a view you have to set datasource and delegate..and also you have to check in appdelegate  file that a object of your view controller have been made or not... i.e. you have to allocate memory of your view controller in app delegate file..